# What is wrong with the listener for request.end in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started working on Node.js. I cam across a tutorial in http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/, I am trying to execute a script he has given as an example, but it is not working unless i comment out the listener on 'end' event.

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
 // request.on("end", function () {
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
  // });
  //request.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

The above code is working fine if i am commenting the listener on 'end' for request, but if i un comment it then it is not working correctly.Can somebody help me out here.

Thanks,
Harsha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually the request on `end` event listener is doing is listen for an end event and trigger a callback function after that event is executed.

You are trying to trigger an `end` event even before that event has been executed. Move the request `end` function outside the response body and that should work:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {    
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });    

    request.on("end", function () {      
        console.log("GOOD BYE!");       
    });

    response.end('Hello HTTP!'); 
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `end` event is emitted by the after the `response.end()` call, like:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.on('end', function () {
        console.log('end event called');
    });
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8080);
```